# What is the best way to find the maven coordinates of a dependency in order to use a class?

Tags: java

Whenever I look at any documentation page for a Java class, it never specifies the maven coordinates of the dependency I need in order to use the class. I have to find the maven coordinates by doing additional searches. Why is it like that? Below is an example:
[image]

In contrast this is a C# documentation page:
[image]
It clearly specifies that in order to use this class, I will need to add a reference to `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll`. Is this another example of how Java sucks compared to C#?

Comment: Maven is a dependency manager and build tool; you might use sbt, gradle or ant/ivy.

Comment: JavaDoc was developed a long time before Maven, it's intention wasn't to provide dependency requirements, but information about the class and it's methods

Comment: It only sucks because you're not familiar with it... a simple Google search gives you the maven dependency - or you could find it on AWS website or on maven central...

Comment: You don't need any maven instructions to use a class; IF you use maven, you need to configure it to use a library that contains the class. The documentation on configuring maven, if the provider of the library chooses to provide it, belongs with the library, not the class. I do NOT want javadoc for every class littered up with everything I need to use it with maven, gradle, ant, subversion, git, Ruby on Rails, and my Visa rewards card. If you really don't like Java, find a job where you don't have to use it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about why a documentation website was designed a certain way, not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever I look at any documentation page for a Java class, it never specifies the maven coordinates of the dependency I need in order to use the class.

You are currently looking at the javadocs for the class.  The Maven coordinates don't belong there<sup>1</sup>.

What you need to do is to look for the documentation for the library (or whatever) that the class belongs to.  If the library documentation is well written, it will tell you the Maven coordinates, probably in the "getting started" section.

The other approach is to use to use a search tool to identify the name of the distribution JAR file, then try to find that in Maven Central.  That won't tell you which version of the library is best to use.  For that you need to read the library's documentation; e.g. the release notes or change logs.

**UPDATE** - In this case, finding the Maven coordinates in the Amazon documentation is challenging.  (They seem to think we should all be using their Eclipse plugin ...)  However, a little bit of digging and here is the Maven Central query to list all available versions:

- http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22com.amazonaws%22%20AND%20a%3A%22aws-java-sdk%22

---

<sup>1 - Please don't presume to tell the Java community that they have got it all wrong, just because they don't conform to your expectations.  If you think Java sucks, find a job where you don't need to use it.  Or at least, keep your unwanted opinions to yourself.</sup>